# Python: What is the most optimised way to count number of 0's from a list of 0's and 1's without using any in-build functions?

Tags: python, memory-management

Well, I went to an interview recently and the guy asked me this question.

```
What is the most optimised way to count number of 0's from a list of 0's and 1's without using any in-build functions? (Python)
```

I guess he meant it in the terms of memory management as well.

I wasn't too sure about the answer as the these were the only 2 things coming to my mind.

```
First, a python in-build functional called count. For example
a = [1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]
print a.count(0)
```

But, it is without using any in-build function , so the next thing which was coming to my mind was a for loop.

```
counter = 0
for zeros in a:
    if zeros == 0:
        counter = counter + 1
print counter
```

This would also give the answer and without using any in-build function but I don't think it is the most optimised way of doing it as it looping over the list again and again.

Could someone help me out with this with some explanation? Thanks

Comment: What? Your answer loops over `a` precisely once.

Comment: You could get rid of the `if` with `counter += 1 - zeros`, I'm not in the mood to time it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, copy this to an IDE and use a debug point and see it yourself.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is correct though, your code loops over the list once.

Comment: I don't need to, it is obvious you only loop once. You can check the byte-code directly if you want using the `dis` module.

Comment: @sam: It goes through the loop body repeatedly, but "looping over the list" refers to executing the entire loop over the entire list, which you only do once.

Comment: The idea of most optimized without using built-ins is kind of an oxymoron. From an algorithms standpoint, it should be easy to prove theta(n), therefore a for loop is time optimal, within a constant factor. And it obviously uses O(1) space.

Comment: Note that `count` also needs to loop over the list. It's just faster because it's written in C.

Comment: another way might be print len([x for x in a if not x]) which I expect to perform horribly, because it allocates a pointless temporary list, but at least you have another option to measure the for loop against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, I did a few timings.

```
import timeit

setup1 = '''
a = [1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]*10
def count0(lst):
    c = 0
    for x in lst:
        if x == 0:
            c += 1
    return c
'''

setup2 = '''
a = [1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]*10
def count0(lst):
    c = 0
    for x in lst:
        c += not x
    return c
'''

setup3 = '''
a = [1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]*10
def count0(lst):
    c = 0
    for x in lst:
        c += 1 - x
    return c
'''

setup4 = '''
a = [1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]*10
def count0(lst):
    c = 0
    for x in lst:
        c += 1^x
    return c
'''

print(min(timeit.Timer('count0(a)', setup=setup1).repeat(10, 100000)))
print(min(timeit.Timer('count0(a)', setup=setup2).repeat(10, 100000)))
print(min(timeit.Timer('count0(a)', setup=setup3).repeat(10, 100000)))
print(min(timeit.Timer('count0(a)', setup=setup4).repeat(10, 100000)))
```

> 0.276657819748
>   0.35341501236
>   0.265990972519
>   0.320657014847

2.7.5

Comment: The first person to post a quick "do this" answer came up with the slowest option. And that's why you timeit, because ANYBODY can screw up optimization -- you have to measure. Do you think it was slow because it did several type conversions to execute addition and logical not?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution requires O(N) time and O(1) space. I'd make some adjustments to your code though.

```
counter = 0
for el in a:
    counter += not el
print(counter)
```

prevents you from checking whether the element is zero N times and takes advantage of the fact booleans in python are ints 0 or 1

alternatively if you can use len

```
counter = len(a)
for el in a:
    counter -= el
print(counter)
```

Comment: For the O(n) argument, you posted no proof. If you think adding the numbers is faster, show the timeit.  (If you do timeit, can you run count vs sum on the built-ins, too?)

Comment: `len` is a builtin so I don't think we may use it.

Comment: It's an unsorted list. Whether you are filtering it from 1s or anything it is going to take a minimum of O(N) time to traverse it. Sorting it will take greater complexity. I don't need to time it if we are just talking theory. The rest of my answer was suggestions to limit comparisons not just a copy of his code.

Comment: I'm just saying if you post an answer, do the proof if you're talking big-oh, do the measurement if you're trying to get a better constant. Many people already covered the O(n) in comments.  The measurements have now shown your hasty answer to be the slowest, but humans always screw up optimization -- you have to measure.

Comment: Good news, while not the best option, your answer does comfortably beat the OP's code in my timeit.  I used a much longer list than timgeb. So there's some redemption for you.